# Codeigniter: Form validation is_unique  error not showing

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am using the below line to check my add user form to check if the email address does not exist in my database  I have  a feeling that it is working fine but I am unable to get any error messages.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userEmail','E-Mail', 'required|valid_email|trim|max_length[99]|xss_clean|is_unique[users.email]');
```

In my view I have `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>`

My controller is formatted as per below:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
        {
            $userData = array(
                'fName' => $this->input->post('userFirstName', TRUE),
                'lName' => $this->input->post('userLastName', TRUE),
                'email' => $this->input->post('userEmail', TRUE),
                'password' => sha1($this->input->post('userPassword', TRUE))
            );  

            $this->db->escape($userData);
            $this->user_model->addUser($userData);
        }
```

Comment: Your callback doesn't return anything, it doesn't even execute the database query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my controller to the following:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userEmail','E-Mail', 'required|valid_email|trim|max_length[99]|xss_clean|is_unique[users.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userPassword','Password', 'required|trim|max_length[99]|xss_clean');

        if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
            {
                $userData = array(
                    'fName' => $this->input->post('userFirstName', TRUE),
                    'lName' => $this->input->post('userLastName', TRUE),
                    'email' => $this->input->post('userEmail', TRUE),
                    'password' => sha1($this->input->post('userPassword', TRUE))
                );  

                $this->db->escape($userData);
                $this->user_model->addUser($userData);
            }

            $data['contentMangement'] = $this->options_model->systemOptions();
            $data['pageTitle'] = 'Add User';
            $this->load->view('_assets/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('addUser', $data);
            $this->load->view('_assets/footer');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the is_unique predefined validation rule. Pass the table name and column name for the email column.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userEmail','E-Mail', 'required|valid_email|trim|max_length[99]|xss_clean|is_unique[users.email]');
```

Answer (score 0):

we must add to **table name** for **is_unique**
in my way for exp.

```
array(
            'field' => 'email',
            'label' => 'email',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
            'errors' => array('required'  => 'Please enter a %s.','valid_email' => 'Please enter a valid %s.','is_unique' => 'email already exist.')
        ),
```

hope you under stand.